# The second and third dimension of a 3-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

How can I copy second and third dimension of a 3-dimensional array, which is absolutely a 2-dimensional array, into another 3-dimensional array?
The following code generate an empty array(b).
The following is just concept code.

```
   int a[ 12 ][ 51 ][ 4 ];
    int b[ 20 ][ 51 ][ 4 ];  
    int main()
       int i;
        for( i= 0; i< 12 ; i++)
        {
            memcpy(b[i], a, sizeof(a));
            }
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do NOT worry about efficiency.  The very small size of this data makes any efficiency considerations immaterial.  Thus, do NOT use memcpy in this problem.  Rather, try something more explicit:

```
   int a[ 12 ][ 51 ][ 4 ];
   int b[ 20 ][ 51 ][ 4 ];  
   int main()
   {
        int eni, i, j;
        for( eni = 0; eni < 12 ; eni++)
        {
          for (i = 0; i < 51; i++)
          {
             for (j = 0, j < 4; j++)
             {
              b[eni][i][j] = a[eni][i][j];
             }
          }
        }
        return 0;
  }
  // Note. the above code has not been tested, I just threw-it-up here for discussion.
```

When you have this working, then try a version that uses the fact that C stores arrays in row major form.  Or just use the above code as-is.  That is, you might have more important tasks to work on in the overall project?

Comment: Thank you but I really want to use "memcopy" or anything with high performance copying tool because this program would be used for large arrays too.